# Expanded form in C# validation toggle

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a radio button list which expands a section of a form depending on which item is selected. While I've got this working, how do I switch off the validation for the (additional) form items when the form is not in the expanded state? Do I group the expanded section form control validations and turn off that validation group? Is that the best way to do it and if so, how do I do that in C#.net?

Comment: Just to be clear, I have 1 form (1 submit button), which is submitting data to 2 tables. Submission of data (and hence validation) to one of the tables is optional (toggle on/off).

Comment: I think you need to specify which form, winforms, asp.net, wpf or silverlight?

Comment: should I just toggle the enable state of each one?

Comment: already mentioned... C#.net above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite your answer as follows:

```
private void showAgencyFrm()
{
    bool isAgentActivated = agentActivated();
    agencyFrm.Visible = isAgentActivated;
    companynameValidator.Enabled = isAgentActivated;
    companyphoneValidator.Enabled = isAgentActivated;
    companyaddressValidator.Enabled = isAgentActivated;
    postcodeValidator.Enabled = isAgentActivated;
}
```

It's easier to read (and thus, maintain) and it removes the `if (true) then (true) else (false)` logic.

Answer (score 0):

I figured, here is what I used:

```
private void showAgencyFrm()
    {
        if (agentActivated())
        {
            agencyFrm.Visible = Visible;
            companynameValidator.Enabled = companyphoneValidator.Enabled = companyaddressValidator.Enabled = postcodeValidator.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            agencyFrm.Visible = false;
            companynameValidator.Enabled = companyphoneValidator.Enabled = companyaddressValidator.Enabled = postcodeValidator.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```